# How to make custom time and date picker flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, datepicker, timepicker

I make an app which requires date and time picker but I don't want to use Flutter's prewritten widgets I want to create my one.
Here is what I want to achieve:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKEps.jpg 
At first, I want to start with time picker, I think that I can use listview with numbers but the question arises how can I get selected data, probably I need to track scroll position or smth like that.

 Perhaps, you guys can give me some help.

Comment: You should maybe take a look at this package (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_datetime_picker)

Comment: no, it's not what I'm looking for